# List Sort Issue

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm currently learning python, and I've been having issues concerning the sort() function.

```
lenght = int(input())
list_string = input()
l = list_string.split(' ')
l.sort()
print(l)
```

For instance, the first input gets the length of the list, then the user enters the list with spaces betwenn each integer

> 3 4 5 5 6

The issue is that when I sort this list:

> 3 7 8 5 12 14 21 13 18

I get:

> ['12', '13', '14', '18', '21', '3', '5', '7', '8']

Which is really confusing since I don't have any clue of why it does that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that those are still strings (not `int`s) and therefore are ordered alphabetically, meaning all strings starting with 1 first etc.

If you want to treat the numbers as numbers, you should do this first:

```py
l = [int(x) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you didn't convert the numbers to `int` so it is sorted considering elements as `str` objects.

You can use `map` to do so as:

```
l = list(map(int, list_string.split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains strings, so they are [ordered lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). You can sort your list by int value [by using the `key` argument to `list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```
l.sort(key=int)
```

Your list will still be the original list of strings, not integers, after that. We only sorted by int value, not converted the list elements.

The sorting works by temporally converting the elements in the list to integers, and sort the according to their integer value. In general `key` can be any one argument function, which will be applied to each element *before* sorting.

The other answers show how to convert your list to integers.